# Modifying .desktop file to scale application display

Tags: fedora, kde, desktop, display, exec

I'm using the KDE desktop with Fedora 27 on two different machines.

I found a handy trick for scaling Spotify by modifying the .desktop file in /usr/share/applications as such:

Exec=spotify **--force-device-scale-factor=1.5** %U

Why does it modify some applications and not others. For instance, it works great on Spotify but has no effect on Intellij or Rstudio.

I have found other workarounds for those programs for the time being, except for Intellij on my other machine. It would be great if I could use the --force-device-scale-factor successfully on all applications.  Does it depend on mime settings ?